# How can mixin know type parameters of generic superclass

Tags: scala, generics, mixins

Let's assume I have a generic type like this one:

```
class GenericEchoer[T <: Any] {
    var content: T = _
    def echo: String = "Echo: " + content.toString
}
```

Then it is possible to create a mixin that would allow to extend functionality of GenericEchoer[T] like this:

```
trait Substitution[T <: AnyRef] extends GenericEchoer[T] {
    def substitute(newValue: T) = { content = newValue }
}
```

Having those defined, I can instantiate type in this way:

```
val echoer = new GenericEchoer[Int] with Substitution[Int]
```

My question is: how to implement similar functionality so that I can omit type parameters in the mixin? In other words, I'd like to be able to instantiate the same type with the following line:

```
val echoer = new GenericEchoer[Int] with Substitution
```

This, however, does not work, as Substitution "doesn't know" the underlying type parameter.

Comment: If `Substitution` extends `GenericEchoer` then `Susbstitution with GenericEchoer` extends `GenericEchoer` twice. You might like to fix that. Also why do you constrain the type `T <: AnyRef` then try to use `Int` which is most definitely not an `AnyRef`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is wrong, it won't even compile.

Your `GenericEchoer` cannot be a `class`, cause your `content` member is abstract, or you should init this with a default value:

```
class GenericEchoer[T <: AnyRef] {
    var content: T = _
    def echo: String = "Echo: " + T.toString
}
```

You can't write `T.toString`, i guess you wanted `content.toString`. You can't pass `Int` to it, cause `Int` has `AnyVal` as its supertype, and your upper bound of `T` is `AnyRef`.

`self.content` in `Substitution` is also illegal, you should:

1) make `self` as a selftype:

```
trait Substitution[T <: AnyRef] extends GenericEchoer[T] { self =>
    def substitute(newValue: T) = { self.content = newValue }
}
```

2) Replace it with `this`
3) Just leave `{ content = newValue }`

As for your problem. No it's not possible. I can suggest you replace `class` with a `trait` and type constructor with an abstract type member:

```
trait GenericEchoer {
  type T <: AnyRef  
  var content: T = _
  def echo: String = "Echo: " + content.toString
}

trait Substitution extends GenericEchoer {
  def substitute(newValue: T) { content = newValue }
}

val enchoer = new GenericEchoer with Substitution { type T = String }
```

or better

```
val enchoer = new GenericEchoer with Substitution { 
  type T = String 
  var content = "Hello" // either case it will be null
}
```

Comment: OK, I fixed the mistakes you pointed out. I haven't thought about using type member - thank you.